# I don't see iBus and can't install Korean (Hangul)

Tags: language-support, input, korean

I have read all the posts about asking how to install Korean (Hangul) on this computer. I'm new to Ubuntu and not sure what is iBus and cannot find it on Dashboard (which I'm guessing is the one on the very top on left side and also pops open with Windows key). I'm only trying to install Korean (Hangul) so that I can type Korean. It only types English.

I have tried looking up iBus on Dashboard; nothing comes out. 
When I search for "input", it shows these items:

[image: "input" search results]

Could anyone please tell me what I need to get my Korean installed?

Comment: You open terminal with ctrl+alt+T and type `ibus-setup` but I don't think that answer works properly anymore.  Use the answer posted below instead.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: Correct, on Ubuntu you should normally _not_ use `ibus-setup` directly any longer.

Answer (score 3):

- open **Language Support**.
- Click <kbd>Install/Remove Languages...</kbd>, there will be pop-up.

[image]

- Choose "Korean" from the list, tick the checkbox, apply then, and wait.

[image]

[image]

- If the process is done, make sure you **log out** here and **log back** in otherwise you'll missing "Korean (Hangul)" option on Text Entry.
- Hit <kbd>Super</kbd> (windows key) and open "Text Entry" application.
- Press the <kbd>+</kbd> sign and then type "Korean" and select it.  Then you’ll see a screen like this. Choose Korean (Hangul) (Ibus).

[image]

You can now select your Hangul mode from language indicator.
[image]

[image]

행운을 빌어 요 여모훋ㅈㅂ <-- Test only.

Comment: Still valid for Ubuntu 18.04